# Park domain on Google Compute cloud instance

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine

I have couple of Virtual instances created on Google Compute engine, one of which has nginx installed to server my static web pages..
I followed [Google Cloud dns configuration](https://www.zeitgeist.se/2014/05/01/google-cloud-dns-how-to/) guide

I have created all entries beside CNAME, I have verified domain ownership of my domain using Compute -> App Engine -> Settings , wasn't sure if its required but i still did.

I can access my website using the static IP address of the instance,But when i try to access it using the domain, i get 404 with google broken bot page.
If i add my verified domain to the Project and try to access the domain, i still get 404 but without google bot page.

DNS check says my 'A' record are correctly pointed to the ip address of the instance.

In both error pages i can see that response header Server is either GHS, or Google Frontend, its never reaching my nginx instance

I am not sure where to look, any pointers??

Comment: Can you post the DNS lookup result (re: because you can actually get to the site using IP, I think the issue is more DNS than anything). I'm a Windows dude, so apologies if this isn't relevant: Do `host headers` matter (setup) so your web server "knows" which site (among x sharing the IP) is what is being requested? Hth...

Comment: @EdSF its was problem with my isp provider, its working fine from other places..

Answer (score 1):

its seems there is some DNS problem with my wifi provider.. its working just fine from sf.
not sure how to close the question now..

Comment: DNS propagation (to your ISP)? Interesting site BTW :) Best ~ You can mark our own answer as the answer (to "close").